# Patebin api returning "Bad API request, use POST request, not GET" for requests.post in python?

Tags: python, pastebin

I am trying to use patebin api from python using requests.post which sends out a post request, my code is

```
# importing the requests library
import requests

# defining the api-endpoint
API_ENDPOINT = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"

# your API key here
API_KEY = "my api key"

# your source code here
source_code = '''
print("Hello, world!")
a = 1
b = 2
print(a + b)
'''

# data to be sent to api
data = {'api_dev_key':API_KEY,
        'api_option':'paste',
        'api_paste_code':source_code,
        'api_paste_format':'python'}

# sending post request and saving response as response object
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)

# extracting response text
pastebin_url = r.text
print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)
```

The curl post request as given in the documentation works for my api key and I got the paste url.

But I am getting **Bad API request, use POST request, not GET** output for the above python code does anyone has any suggetions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple fix, as @LeventeKovács points out, is to change the request type in your URL from "http" to "https".  Here's why the Requests library doesn't do what you want/expect with your current URL...

You are doing a HTTP request to a HTTPS endpoint.  This requires a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.  When handling this redirect, the Requests library changes the POST to a GET, with this code:

```
# Second, if a POST is responded to with a 301, turn it into a GET.
# This bizarre behaviour is explained in Issue 1704.
if response.status_code == codes.moved and method == 'POST':
    method = 'GET'
```

Here's a link the the issue mentioned in the comment associated this code:

> https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1704

That issue cites this part of the HTTP spec:

> 301 Moved Permanently If the 301 status code is received in response
> to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT
> automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the
> user, since this might change the conditions under which the request
> was issued. Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after
> receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents will
> erroneously change it into a GET request.

and then seems to go on to rationalize the code's behavior by saying that the Requests library should do what most/all browsers currently do, which is to change the POST to a GET and retry at the new address.

Comment: As told by @LeventeKovács I just changed the http to https and it did the work for me , but still Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you described. I solved it using **https** in the API link instead of **http**.

My suggestion to try is:
API_ENDPOINT = "https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"